# print char to console application

Tags: c++, c, char

This is really simple question but I'm totally confused. I want to print the output of a function in my console application. My function is :

```
   void Func(char * x)
```

and I call it as:

```
char a;
Func(& a);
```

Now I want to print my character string (a) in console application in VS2010. What should I do?

Comment: Can you post your Func code?

Comment: `a` is not a "character string". It's just one character.

Comment: Do you want to print inside the function (the `x`) or outside the function (the `a`)?

Comment: I'm guessing there's a fundamental misunderstanding here between a character (the `char`) and a C-style string (the `char*`).

Comment: void FUNC(char * x) { x = (char *) data.buf}, data.buf is char array and I want to retrieve this char array from FUNC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, what you're passing to the function is not a *string*, but merely a pointer to a single character.

you ask what you should do to print that character.

technically, it is as easy as this:

```
#include <iostream>

void Func( char* x )
{
    std::cout << *x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    char a = 'G';
    Func( &a );
}
```

but while this works *technically*, there’s much that will, so to speak, jump up out of the toilet and *bite you* in a larger program…

so let’s start with the **function signature**: its arguments and result. if the point is that the function should provide a value for the variable used as actual argument, then choose a function result rather than a pointer argument. and then don’t do any i/o in the function, because that then limits its utility, what it can be used for:

```
#include <iostream>

char Func()
{
    return 'A';
}

int main()
{
    char const a = Func();
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

if, on the other hand, the point is merely that the function should display (or do something with) the character value, then pass it by value, like this:

```
#include <iostream>

void Func( char const x )
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    char const a = 'N';
    Func( a );
}
```

if, on the third hand, the idea really is to pass a string, then use a `std::string` – but then we're off into less probable possibilities, of which there is an abundance, too much to cover in this answer

Answer (score 1):

```
std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

or if using C-:

```
printf("%c\n", a);
```

Comment: That `C-` is because of not being `C++`?